# Outputting a variable via TreatAsContent(@QR_Code) into email doesn't render the image due to the image's src attribute changing during email send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

I have a transactional email that is triggered via API - and one of the data points being passed in is a QR Code link.  The data for this is simply an `<img>` tag that hits up Google's API to generate the QR Code.  See below for how it's integrated into the email.

[image]

When I Preview/Test the email, the QR code shows up:

[image]

But when I "Send" the email to myself either through API or a Preview/Test send, here's what I get:
[image]

When I "View Source" on that email, here's what I see as the `<img>` tag:

```
<img src="https://secure-web.cisco.com/1u6aHwYBTsi-4SBCj9mZfYSdLwSfkfpl0gXlb2MS0LtjHU6vq6sZ2mE7J_ug8XI5TuBpMczEBcl_WpmmYKGjF2CSxwxrNWoTFM76vlRayiTaLIogIhuXBlpjZVlZO5wuU2Q7CINfLDzqaD9BqqMIVsOgmvPgq5yzLwll9H5VsZkG_XiZ1m4T1qzAkn1QVphUn3VSnxLbWz4A0Vo64pCp6TWNMLordLKxmUmVFbRVIneUeQFo7g9N3AQvz4FkX17J8TpfS4SsLncsVQi0fVam2tP93RLUgh94wTrUtzShFR_uy73pzGCE7IbdaJMxu3GLGoGNnZZWDPsV4lt5wlSo0RqOFm32ZY5dyxY8vr531WqssYxQLcPJbKdrvzq97YJZVZxSy0XKMHpyZrIaKTmTp_hd-TE1Hs_BLygEBBl3LDM3V73LaO0e73BMdNB6ec2Btf5WsSP87icrr4M0o-TVCPKPywpbTHiWjgItkGqBjK44BG2Gu2Xn9KwY5qlRS8GIh/https%3A%2F%2Fchart.googleapis.com%2Fchart%3Fchs%3D300x300%26cht%3Dqr%26chl%3DRecipient name: Sam Douglas%0AAppointment date and time: Monday, March 08, 2021 1:15 PM%0AClinic name: Johny Medical Facility%0AClinic location: 23 Stanford Rd, Concord, New Hampshire 03301%0AClinic phone: %0Ahttps://sonhdev1-sonh-community.cs32.force.com/providers/s/vams-clinic-recipient-check-in?recordId=a20r0000001b0hq" alt="Scan QR code to open record." border="0">
```

Clearly it's not the same URL.  What can I do to resolve this?  I'm at a loss!!!

Comment: I get the feeling this is because of a sandbox caching service for your business email address. `secure-web.cisco.com` sounds like a service many businesses use to create a buffer on images to help increase security by not having the images render locally. You might want to try sending to a personal account like gmail to verify if this is just due to your corporate process or an actual issue.

Comment: @Gortonington indeed this was the case.  My work email's server is what's causing this.  Gmail works fine.  Appreciate the comment!